# PixiJS - Using multiple masks on a sprite

Tags: pixi.js

I'm new to PixiJS and I can't figure this out. I understand you can set a mask on an object like so:

```
mainSprite.mask = maskSprite
```

But what if you need to set more than one mask on the mainSprite? I tried using a PIXI.Container but it's not working... Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best way but you can add multiple sprites to a container, then create a texture from the container and use that as the mask

```
let container = new PIXI.Container();

for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    let sprite = new PIXI.Sprite(TEXTURE);
    sprite.position.set(POSITION)
    container.addChild(sprite)
}

let mask = new PIXI.Sprite(RENDERER.generateTexture(container));
```

just replace the relevant variables and this should work

Comment: That's it, thanks! However the syntax should be:
var mask = new PIXI.Sprite(renderer.generateTexture(container));

Comment: Actually, this leads me to another question. Is it possible to make the masks move independently using this method?

Comment: ah yes ive swapped that round now. 

You could update the positions of the individual sprites, generate the texture, and set the mask each frame .

Doing that would be expensive so maybe avoid updating the mask all the time. Depending on your situation updating the mask every couple of frames may be good enough.

Comment: Alright thanks :) It's weird that such a thing can be that complicated with Pixijs, when it could be so easily done with a mere vanilla 2D canvas context, though.

Comment: @TheCat Pixi.js is mainly using webgl - and webgl is unfortunately more complicated than "vanilla canvas" - but gives more performance.